# How to merge two list in one alternating elements from both

Tags: r, list

I have two list of GGPLOT objects (charts):

> SD

$`NCED3 - DN7756_c0_g1`

$`SVP - DN2362_c0_g1`

$`PYL4 - DN76611_c0_g1`

$`PYL10 - DN5056_c0_g1`

$`ICE1 - DN3803_c1_g5`

$`AHG3 - DN4648_c0_g1`

$`ABF2 - DN1262_c0_g3`

$`ABI3 - DN3814_c0_g1`

and

> LD

$`NCED3 - DN16845_c3_g1`

$`SVP - DN16025_c2_g1`

$`PYL4 - DN6782_c0_g1`

$`PYL10 - DN17323_c1_g1`

$`ICE1 - DN16653_c3_g1`

$`AHG3 - DN17323_c2_g6`

$`ABF2 - DN16572_c0_g1`

$`ABI3 - DN16033_c4_g1`

I want to merge both lists in one, but I need to alternate elements from both lists (notice that the name of the entries for both lists coincide at the same list positions). As far, it works as follows:

`plot_list <- list(LD[[1]], SD[[1]], LD[[2]], SD[[2]], LD[[3]], SD[[3]],LD[[4]], SD[[4]], LD[[5]], SD[[5]], LD[[6]], SD[[6]], LD[[7]], SD[[7]], LD[[8]], SD[[8]])`

However I need a new syntax because I need to use the script on several list of different lengths. There is a way to get the list without calling the elements one by one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cbind` then `t` and finaly `unlist`.

```
x <- list(sd = list(a=1, b=2, c=3), ld = list(a=4, b=5, c=6))

unlist(t(do.call(cbind, x)))
#do.call(cbind, x) |> t() |> unlist() #Alternative
#[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

In case there are different types:

```
unlist(asplit(do.call(cbind, x), 1), FALSE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `transpose` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
transpose(x) %>% 
   unlist(use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
 unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = c, x)), use.names = FALSE)
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

#### data

```
x <- list(sd = list(a=1, b=2, c=3), ld = list(a=4, b=5, c=6))
```